# Express JS CORS when requested via browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, passport-facebook

While using an Express/NodeJS backend - I have a REST GETTER that is used to authenticate using strava (passport-strava)

When I invoke the API URL directly(http://localhost:3000/api/auth/strava) - the connection is successful and I'm able to retrieve the profile information.
However, when this is invoked through a browser widget, i.e. onClick of a HTML button and routed through to the backend - I'm thrown an error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fstrava%2Fcallback&client_id=9769. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I do understand that this is related to CORS and that the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" must be included however, there is no respite on adding this into the header with the appropriate value.

I tried to intercept the calls using chrome://net-internals to check if Access-Control-Allow-Origin is being stripped out and noticed the variations in calls -

When called directly via the API - the calls are as follows

```
1097271 URL_REQUEST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/strava
1097273 DISK_CACHE_ENTRY    http://localhost:3000/api/auth/strava
1097275 HTTP_STREAM_JOB https://www.strava.com/
1097276 CONNECT_JOB ssl/www.strava.com:443
1097277 CONNECT_JOB ssl/www.strava.com:443
1097278 SOCKET  ssl/www.strava.com:443
1097279 CONNECT_JOB ssl/www.strava.com:443
1097280 CONNECT_JOB ssl/www.strava.com:443
1097281 SOCKET  ssl/www.strava.com:443
1097282 DISK_CACHE_ENTRY    https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fstrava%2Fcallback&client_id=9769
1097283 HTTP_STREAM_JOB https://www.strava.com/
1097285 URL_REQUEST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/strava
1097288 DISK_CACHE_ENTRY    http://localhost:3000/api/auth/strava
1097290 HTTP_STREAM_JOB https://www.strava.com/
1097291 DISK_CACHE_ENTRY    https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fstrava%2Fcallback&client_id=9769
1097292 HTTP_STREAM_JOB https://www.strava.com/
1097293 DISK_CACHE_ENTRY    http://localhost:3000/api/auth/strava/callback?state=&code=7b5722c72f079ee2ac5dfeb7d5140cdc6375f5cc
```

However, when routed via the widget the calls are as follows

```
1097337 URL_REQUEST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/strava
1097339 DISK_CACHE_ENTRY    http://localhost:3000/api/auth/strava
1097344 URL_REQUEST https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fstrava%2Fcallback&client_id=9769
1097346 DISK_CACHE_ENTRY    https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fstrava%2Fcallback&client_id=9769
1097347 HTTP_STREAM_JOB https://www.strava.com/
1097348 CONNECT_JOB pm/ssl/www.strava.com:443
1097349 CONNECT_JOB pm/ssl/www.strava.com:443
1097350 HOST_RESOLVER_IMPL_JOB  www.strava.com
1097352 SOCKET  pm/ssl/www.strava.com:443
1097353 CONNECT_JOB pm/ssl/www.strava.com:443
1097354 SOCKET  pm/ssl/www.strava.com:443
```

The difference that I seemed to pull out is the additional call

```
1097344 URL_REQUEST https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fstrava%2Fcallback&client_id=9769
```

which isn't made in the previous scenario.

These observations are made not only for the passport-strava package but the passport-facebook package as well. Therefore, I think there is something gravely incorrect that I'm doing to get into this state.

Any assistance is well appreciated.

Comment: You can use this plugin to enable cors headers on your server.  [CORS plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that - but setting the origin also didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know about CORS then I go into any details.

Basically your issue is with your `REST server`, it needs to set the response packet's header with the appropriate content so that the browser doesn't complain. Unfortunately this is a security feature.

So in your server code, you need to define a function that would do the above and set it as 1 of the middleware layer that express will have to parse when a HTTP comes through.

**Example**:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var httpAccessControlPolicy = function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type,Accept,X-Access-Token,X-Key,Authorization');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);

  next();
};

app.use(httpAccessControlPolicy);
```

Yes. As pointed out by 1 of the commenter the npm module `cors` can also do the job.

**CORS**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

If you are intending to use it then you might be looking at this example usage:

```
var express = require('express')
  , cors = require('cors')
  , app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get('/products/:id', function(req, res, next){
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'});
});

app.listen(80, function(){
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80');
});
```

Comment: That's perhaps the first thing I did. However, I still get into this tizzy in one of the scenarios, and that is when the api is requested(invoked) indirectly, say via a UI button or another rest redirect. I do agree that there is a problem with my REST server but I'm not sure how to find out.

Comment: Are you doing some oauth2 authentication here? Sounds like the external service is instructing your browser to make a call to 1 of your endpoint and it isn't able to read the response due the response header is missing the CORS info. Hence the browser is blocking it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, @samuel. I'm not doing anything different - I'll try the example listed on [the facebook passport github example](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-facebook-example) and trace it from there

Comment: You are right - there is something cancelling the requests sent. Incidentally when the call does not work this is what i see on the chrome://net-internal `t=46517 [st=16]        DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=1]
                       --> delegate_info = "AsyncResourceHandler"
t=46518 [st=17]     -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE
t=46518 [st=17]      CANCELLED
` I'm unable to identify what is cancelling the request!